# Getting record from another table with id recognition

Tags: php, mysql

there are tables artist, track, & etc
in the artist table there is :
**id**
name
cover
desc

and in the track table there is :
id
name
desc
**artistid**

so if i goto track.php?id=1 and then they print
id
name
desc
**artistid** i want to make this show the record from artist table with id recognition

and can you show me how to make multiple filter from recordset. because i have field "pubid" when the value is 1 this mean publish and then if the value is 2 this mean unpublish

sorry bad english
thx u so much

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SQL Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). In order to only get records which may be published, you'll have to add another `WHERE` clause. Like:

`SELECT name, desc FROM track WHERE id = $id AND pubid = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

track.php?id=1
or
track.php?id=1&pubid=1
track.php?id=1&pubid=2

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $artistid = $_GET['id'];
    if (isset($_GET['pubid'])) {
        $pudid = $_GET['pubid']; 
        $sql = "select `id`, `name` from `track` where `artistid` = {$artistid} and `pubid` = {$pupid} order by `desc`";

    } else
        $sql = "select `id`, `name` from `track` where `artistid` = {$artistid} order by `desc`";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) !== false) {
       echo $row['name'];
    }
}
```